# Concurrent access to a public field. Why is it possible to observe inconsistent state?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm reading B. Goetz Java Concurrency In practice and now I'm at the `section 3.5` about safe publication. He stated:

```
// Unsafe publication
public Holder holder;
public void initialize() {
    holder = new Holder(42);
}
```

> This improper publication could allow another thread to observe a
>   partially constructed object.

I don't see why it is possible to observe a partially constructed subobject. Assume, that the constructor `Holder(int)` does not allow `this` to escape. So, the constructed reference can be observed only by the caller. Now, as [JLS 17.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7) stated:

> Writes to and reads of references are always atomic, regardless of
>   whether they are implemented as 32-bit or 64-bit values.

it is impossible for thread to observe a partially constructed object.

Where was I wrong?

Comment: btw, I just clicked through to the link you provided with JCIP, and I noticed it's the full text of the book! Afaik, JCIP is still under copyright, and that copy shouldn't be up there. That's something for the github people to monitor and deal with, but imo it's improper to share the link here.

Comment: @yshavit Yes, but I thought since it was published on github, it might as well be published here... I presum Brian Goetz knows about it...

Comment: 'It's on github' is not a guarantee of legal distribution any more than 'I can torrent it'. There is no freely licensed copy of the book on its site http://jcip.net. This is almost certainly a link to a pirated copy and you should remove it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Memory barriers and coding style over a Java VM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964317/memory-barriers-and-coding-style-over-a-java-vm)

Comment: [without final this is proveable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066866/testing-initialization-safety-of-final-fields/59385508#59385508)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> So, the constructed reference can be observed only by the caller.

That's where your logic breaks, though it seems like a perfectly reasonable thing to say.

First things first: The atomicity that 17.7 mentions only says that when you read a reference, you'll either see all of a previous value (starting with its default value of `null`) or all of some subsequent value. You'll never get a reference with some bits corresponding to value 1 and some bits corresponding to value 2, which would essentially make it a reference into a random place in the JVM heap — which would be terrible! Basically they're saying, "the reference itself will either be null, or point to a valid place in memory." But what's *in* that memory, that's where things can get weird.

### Setting up a simple example

I'll assume this simple Holder:

```
public class Holder {
    int value; // NOT final!
    public Holder(int value) { this.value = value; }
}
```

Given that, what happens when you do `holder = new Holder(42)`?

1. the JVM allocates some space for the new Holder object, with default values for all its fields (ie, `value = 0`)
2. the JVM invokes the Holder constructor

   - the JVM sets `<new instance>.value` to the incoming value (42).
   - the constructor completes
3. the JVM returns the reference to that object we just allocated, and sets `Holder.holder` to this new reference

### Reordering makes life hard (but it also makes programs fast!)

The problem is that another thread can view these events in any order, since there are no synchronization points between them. That's because constructors don't have any special synchronization or happens-before semantics (that's slight lie, but more on that later). You can see the full list of "synchronized-with" actions at [JLS 17.4.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4); note that there's nothing there about constructors.

So, another thread might see those actions ordered as (1, 3, 2). This means that if some other event is ordered between events 1 and 3 — for instance, if someone reads `Holder.holder.value` into a local var — then they'll see that newly allocated object, but with its values before the constructor has run: you'd see `Holder.holder.value == 0`. This is called a partially constructed object, and it can be pretty confusing.

If the constructor had multiple steps (setting multiple fields, or setting and then changing a field), then you can see any ordering of those steps. Pretty much all bets are off. Yikes!

### Constructors and `final` fields

I mentioned above that I lied when I asserted that constructors don't have any special synchronization semantics. Assuming you don't leak `this`, there's one exception to that: any `final` fields *are* guaranteed to be seen as they were at the end of the constructor (see [JLS 17.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5)).

You can think of it as there being a kind of synchronization point between steps 2 and 3, but it *only* applies to `final` fields.

- It doesn't apply to non-final fields
- It doesn't apply transitively to other synchronization points.
- It *does*, however, extend to any state that you access through the `final` fields. So, if you have a `final List<String>`, and your constructor initializes it and then adds some values, then all threads are guaranteed to see that list with at least the state that it had at the end of the constructor, including those `add` calls. (If you modify the list after the constructor, without synchronization, then all bets are off again.)

That's why it was important in my example above that `value` was not final. If it had been, then you wouldn't be able to see `Holder.holder.value == 0`.

Comment: `Reordering makes life hard (but it also makes programs fast!)` Percisely, I forgot about this optimization. So, it's possible for JVM to reorder the statements in a way the object will be published with just deafult vaues...

Comment: `If you modify the list after the constructor, without synchronization, then all bets are off again.` I have a question about this. I thought it depended on the list implementation. For instance, if the internal state of the list declared as `volatile`, we observe all state changes, right?

Comment: Yes, that's true. If the list itself is thread safe, you're fine. I should have been clearer about that. :) I meant synchronization in the happens-before sense, which would include writes/reads to volatile fields.

Answer (score 3):

The construction of `Holder` consists roughly of three parts:

1. allocate memory
2. run initialisers
3. assign value field `holder`

However, for performance reasons, these are reordered and will probably run as follows:

1. allocate memory
2. assign value field `holder`
3. run initialisers

So it is possible for a partially constructed Object already to be assigned to a field. From a single threaded perspective this poses no problem whatsoever. But from a multithreaded perspective this leads to obvious problems.

Answer (score 1):

> Now, as JLS 17.7 stated, "Writes to and reads of references are always atomic..."

That might mean less than what you think it means.  All it means is, that the value assigned to a reference variable will never be *torn*.

If some thread updates a non-volatile reference variable that initially referred to object A, changing it to refer to object B instead, then other threads will either see the A reference or the B reference when they examine the variable.  No thread will ever see an invalid reference composed of some bits from the old value and some bits from the new value.

In particular, the requirement that all reference reads and writes be "atomic" does *not* mean that all reference reads and writes have `volatile` semantics.  They don't;  If one thread updates a non-volatile reference variable to point to a newly constructed object, then another thread could get the new reference when it examines the variable, but see the object itself in a partially initialized or uninitialized state.